# What resources can help me understand agriculture for Zeraim?

Tags: product-recommendation, mishna, agriculture

I am studying Mishnayot from Seder Zeraim and I am often having difficulties because I have no idea how agriculture worked in the days of the Second Temple (or even today). Are there any good resources (online or in sefarim, preferably in English) to help me understand how agriculture worked/works, and how that informs the halachot?

Comment: +1 but can use some more clarification

Comment: my chavruta used to lament to me, "if only we were farmers, we'd understand the gemara"

Comment: I think the foreword of the Steinsaltz edition of the talmud does a good job.

Comment: https://books.google.co.cr/books?id=AuYxCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA323&ots=h3e0qDvJ6T&pg=PA323#v=onepage&q&f=false -- footnote 10 has some names of books that discuss agriculture in talmudic times. some may be helpful to you

Comment: Have you seen this Artscroll edition? Seems to have a lots of illustrations: https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422619537.html

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: Yes there are. To name one of the more renowned ones - Prof. Yehuda Felix[‘s books].

Comment: @DoubleAA Why not? He wouldn't like to start farming using methods of the Talmudic age, but would like to understand it in relation with _Seder Zeraim_ in order to better grasp its concepts.

Comment: @Kazi so too all medical questions

Answer (score 3):

The [Koren Steinsaltz HaMishna HaMivueret](https://korenpub.com/collections/the-steinsaltz-mishna-series/products/mishna-hamevoeret) is an excellent Mishna set which is "also accompanied by helpful illustrations, maps, photos, and charts to aid understanding and bring the Mishna into the present day".

For example, [here](https://korenpub.com/cdn/shop/files/look-insideHamishnah-hamev.jpg?v=1675089701&19720) is an excerpt that they provide.